# JavaFX: Retrieve TextField from TextFieldTableCell

Tags: javafx, autocomplete, tableview, tablecell

I have a `TableView` that I want to auto complete it's cells when in editing mode. Here is the code:

```
public static <T > void setEditableColumn(TableColumn<T, String> ){
    TextFieldTableCell textCell = new TextFieldTableCell();
    column.setCellFactory(text.forTableColumn());

}
```

I will use ControlsFX to do the `autocompletion`. My question is how can I access the `TextField` in `textCell`

Comment: There's no way to do that, as far as I am aware. You would need to implement the table cell and factory yourself.

Comment: But if I implement it myself the table will editable regardless  the editable property's value

Comment: What do you mean? Why would that behave any differently?

Comment: Did you try to set textCell  an ID and the use lookup on table?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I mean that I have a TableView that I change it's editable property based on an event, if I implement the cell factory to be a TextField, my TableView will be always editable.